# Hide div permanently until next visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following div with class "`fullscreen`"

```
<div class="fullscreen">
</div>
```

Inside that div, there is a button that once clicked, it will scroll down to anther div that has an ID of "`#page`".

**The question is**, how do I permanently hide the div with the class "`fullscreen`" once scrolled to "`#page`" and settled down? It has not to show again at all until the website has been visited again, even if navigated away from the page and went back to it.

**Please find the live example here, as it will clarify everything: http://loaistudio.com/anita/**

The HTML code of the button:
`<a href="#header">Find Out How</a>`

The JS:

```
//Smooth Scroll
   $('a').click(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
      }, 1500);
      return false;
   });
```

Comment: You should use cookies.

Comment: Look at sessionStorage

Comment: What defines the website as "next visited again"... a different day? A different browser tab/session?

Comment: use session scoped cookies/sessionStorage

Comment: @musefan I guess he means session.

Comment: @dabadaba: You are probably right, but I prefer to seek clarification rather than guess.... seems I am the only one though as everyone else appears to want to jump to the same conclusion as you

Comment: Can anyone please help me to get the function works with sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Final Update:**
I have outlined how to store a value with cookies, localStorage, or server-side sessions below. This is how I would implement these solutions with your posted code:

```
 //Smooth Scroll
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        }, 1500);
        /* We have animated, lets set the variable to never do this again */
        if(supports_storage()) localStorage['nofullscreen'] = true;
        return false;
    });
```

Above, we are setting our localStorage variable (i've named it 'nofullscreen', feel free to replace with whatever makes sense to you) to true, so we know the user has seen our fullscreen already. Now, when the page loads, we want to check for the variable, and act accordingly:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     if(localStorage['nofullscreen'] == 'true') $('.fullscreen').hide();
 });
```

This should hide the div with class "fullscreen" on page load, if the storage variable exists and is 'true'.

---

You'll want to store a cookie on the users machine to know they have visited in the past. You can do so with basic Javascript, like so:

```
document.cookie="nofullscreen=true";
```

The line above will create a cookie in local storage, run this once you've scrolled to #page.

```
function doFullscreen(){
    var name = "nofullscreen=";
    var cookies = document.cookies.split(';');
    cookies.forEach(function(n){
        var c = cookies[i].trim();
        if(c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return false;
    });
```

The function above can run on page load, it will return True if the user has been here before and you should go right to #page, or false if its a new user and you should display the fullscreen div.

**UPDATE: Others have suggested using localStorage, this is also a good idea. here is a small example of that.**

Checking for compatibility:

```
function supports_storage(){
    try{
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Writing to storage:

```
if(supports_storage()) localStorage['sitename.nofullscreen'] = true;
```

Checking the storage:

```
 if(localStorage['sitename.nofullscreen'] == "true"){
      //go right to #page
 }
```

***Update #2: PHP Session Storage***
You've explained in the comments that your using PHP as well. I feel like either of the above solutions would work just as well, but I'll add some PHP code here for completeness.

First, you'll need to start the session:

```
 <?php session_start() ?>
```

You are now able to write to the session with PHP like so:

```
 <?php $_SESSION['nofullscreen']='true'; ?>
```

And check if the session variable is set later with:

```
 <?php if($_SESSION['nofullscreen'] == 'true') { //print css rules to hide #fullscreen here? } ?>
```

If you need to clear the session variable, you can use unset:

```
 <?php unset($_SESSION['nofullscreen']) ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What about a session?

Comment: Sessions are handled server-side, Javascript is not session-aware? Are you using a backend like PHP/Python/NodeJS etc? If so I'd be happy to point you in the right direction, if not localStorage or a simple cookie will be much cleaner.

Comment: I use PHP as well, what would you recommend?

Comment: Loai, I would still recommend using localStorage, but I've edited my answer to show you how to work with the $_SESSION variable in PHP. Happy coding!

Comment: But how will I hide the div once scrolled to the #page and settled only? also what does nofullscreen means, do you mean .fullscreen

Comment: NOFULLSCREEN is simply what i chose to name the variable/cookie. I will update the answer to show you better how to implement the localStorage method, you can substitute for cookies or sessions if you prefer.

Comment: Loai, I've updated the answer to show you how to implement these solutions, see the top!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47780/discussion-between-loai-and-binaryatrocity)

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention the requirement 'even if navigated away from the page and went back to it', you need a way to store state.

There are a few options:

- sessions
- cookies
- local storage (might not work on older browsers)

Take your pick :)

In this case I would probably go with session storage

Comment: Session mate! I think this is the best approach